# WF4 disable copy-paste in WorkflowItemsPresenter in my Custom Sequence

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity, activitydesigner

I'm using WorkflowItemsPresenter in my Custom Sequence Activity and I would like to disable Copy and Paste of activities there. I found some solutions which using ICompositeView interface and I was trying to apply it to WorkflowItemsPresenter but it is not working. Does anyone have any ideas how to disable copy paste behavior in WorkflowItemsPresenter?

Thank you.

Here is my crazy code

BranchSequenceDesigner.xaml

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner x:Class="MyActivities.BranchSequenceDesigner"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
    xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
    >
    <Canvas Name="ContentCanvas" Width="600" Height="600"/>
    <sap:ActivityDesigner.Template>
        <ControlTemplate >
            <sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter Name="test" Items="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Children}">
                <sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter.SpacerTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Drop MyActivity Here !!!!!" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Red" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter.SpacerTemplate>
            </sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </sap:ActivityDesigner.Template>

</sap:ActivityDesigner>
```

BranchSequenceDesigner.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Activities.Presentation;
using System.Activities.Presentation.Model;
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Presentation.Services;

namespace MyActivities
{
    public partial class BranchSequenceDesigner : ICompositeView
    {
        public BranchSequenceDesigner()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnModelItemChanged(object newValue)
        {
            ModelItem canvasActivity = (ModelItem)newValue;
            Update(canvasActivity);
            canvasActivity.Properties["Children"].Collection.CollectionChanged +=
                new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler
                   ((senders, args) => Update(this.ModelItem));
        }

        void Update(ModelItem canvasActivity)
        {

            this.ContentCanvas.Children.Clear();
            foreach (ModelItem modelItem in canvasActivity.Properties["Children"].Collection)
            {
                var view = Context.Services.GetService<ViewService>().GetView(modelItem);
                this.ContentCanvas.Children.Add((UIElement)view);
                DragDropHelper.SetCompositeView((WorkflowViewElement)view, this);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DragDropHelper.AllowDrop(

                    e.Data,
                    this.Context,
                    typeof(Activity)))
            {
                e.Effects = (DragDropEffects.Move & e.AllowedEffects);
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            base.OnDragEnter(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DragDropHelper.AllowDrop(

                    e.Data,
                    this.Context,
                    typeof(Activity)))
            {
                e.Effects = (DragDropEffects.Move & e.AllowedEffects);
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            base.OnDragOver(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewDrop(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            ModelItem canvasActivity = this.ModelItem;
            object droppedItem = DragDropHelper.GetDroppedObject(this, e, this.Context);
            using (ModelEditingScope scope = canvasActivity.BeginEdit())
            {
                ModelItem droppedModelItem = canvasActivity.Properties["Children"].Collection.Add(droppedItem);
                scope.Complete();
            }
            e.Handled = true;
            DragDropHelper.SetDragDropCompletedEffects(e, DragDropEffects.Move);
            base.OnDrop(e);
        }


        bool ICompositeView.CanPasteItems(List<object> itemsToPaste)
        {
            return false;
        }

        System.Activities.Presentation.View.TypeResolvingOptions ICompositeView.DroppingTypeResolvingOptions
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        bool ICompositeView.IsDefaultContainer
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        void ICompositeView.OnItemMoved(System.Activities.Presentation.Model.ModelItem modelItem)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        object ICompositeView.OnItemsCopied(List<System.Activities.Presentation.Model.ModelItem> itemsToCopy)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        object ICompositeView.OnItemsCut(List<System.Activities.Presentation.Model.ModelItem> itemsToCut)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void ICompositeView.OnItemsDelete(List<System.Activities.Presentation.Model.ModelItem> itemsToDelete)
        {
        }

        void ICompositeView.OnItemsPasted(List<object> itemsToPaste, List<object> metadata, Point pastePoint, WorkflowViewElement pastePointReference)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

BranchSequence.cs

```
using System.Activities;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace MyActivities
{
    [Designer(typeof(BranchSequenceDesigner))]
    [ContentProperty("Children")]
    public sealed class BranchSequence : NativeActivity
    {
        [DefaultValue(null)]
        private Collection<Activity> _children;
        public Collection<Activity> Children {
            get
            {
                return (_children = _children ?? new Collection<Activity>());
            }
        }

        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with copy-paste by using CommandBinding from DesignerView.
Here's a helpful [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/10/22/customizing-commands-in-workflow-designer-for-custom-activities-in-vs.aspx)!

```
using System.Activities.Presentation.View;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyActivities
{
    public partial class BranchSequenceDesigner
    {
        public BranchSequenceDesigner()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(this.BaseWorkflowDesigner_Loaded);
        }

        private void BaseWorkflowDesigner_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (CommandBinding cb in this.Designer.CommandBindings)
            {
                if (cb.Command.Equals(ApplicationCommands.Delete))
                {
                    cb.CanExecute += new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(this.OnDeleteCommandCanExecute);
                }
                else if (cb.Command == DesignerView.CopyCommand)
                {
                    cb.CanExecute += new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(this.OnCopyCommandCanExecute);
                }
                else if (cb.Command == DesignerView.PasteCommand)
                {
                    cb.CanExecute += new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(this.OnPasteCommandCanExecute);
                }
                else if (cb.Command == DesignerView.CutCommand)
                {
                    cb.CanExecute += new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(this.OnCutCommandCanExecute);
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnDeleteCommandCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = false;
        }

        private void OnCutCommandCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = false;
        }

        private void OnCopyCommandCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = false;
        }

        private void OnPasteCommandCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = false;
        }
    }
}
```